# Trouble connecting to Sphinx MySQL in development

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, thinking-sphinx

I have Thinking Sphinx installed in my Rails app. Everything works fine in Heroku, but locally I cannot get anything up and running.

When I try to run rake ts:index, I get

```
sh: indexer: command not found
```

When I try to use the search function in the app I get

```
Error connecting to Sphinx via the MySQL protocol. Error connecting to Sphinx via the MySQL protocol. Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61) - SELECT * FROM `book_core` WHERE MATCH('economics') AND `sphinx_deleted` = 0 LIMIT 0, 20 OPTION field_weights=(title=16,author=7); SHOW META
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you don't have Sphinx itself installed:

http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/installing_sphinx.html

If you *do* have it installed but it's still not picking things up, then perhaps the executables are not in your `PATH` environment variable?